# Logical expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How can I transform the logical expressions $(\ref{eq:first})$ into $(\ref{eq:second})$ or $(\ref{eq:second})$ into $(\ref{eq:first})$?
Please show me in a didactic way for a better understanding.

$$
(a \land b \land c) \lor (a \land \lnot b \land \lnot c) \lor (\lnot a \land b \land \lnot c) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b \land c)\label{eq:first}\tag{1}
$$

$$
\{[(a \land b) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b)] \land c\} \lor \{\lnot[(a \land b) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b)] \land \lnot c\}\label{eq:second}\tag{2}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I tried, distributive (a∧b∧c)∨(¬a∧¬b∧c), [(a∧b)∨(¬a∧¬b)]∧c. But how can I rewrite the rest? (a∧¬b∧¬c)∨(¬a∧b∧¬c) into {¬[(a∧b)∨(¬a∧¬b)]∧¬c}

Comment: The truth table is only 8 rows, is that an acceptable method ?

Comment: No, the question asks to use logical sequence to rewrite the sentences.

Comment: using the truth table method, the expressions are equivalent.

Comment: but i'm having trouble rewriting the sentences.

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Start doing the same thing for the rest: take out the $\neg c$ using Distribution.

Then use Distribution on $a \land \neg b$ and $\neg a \land b$: you get $4$ terms:

$(a \lor \neg a) \land (a \lor b) \land (\neg b \lor \neg a) \land (\neg b \lor b)$

$a \lor \neg a$ and $\neg b \lor b$ can be removed by Complement.

Finally, a couple of DeMorgan's and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$
(a \land b \land c) \lor (a \land \lnot b \land \lnot c) \lor (\lnot a \land b \land \lnot c) \lor (\lnot a \land(\lnot b \land c))
\\\equiv[a\land(b= c)]\lor[\lnot a\land(b\ne c)]
\\\equiv a=(b=c)$$

$$
\{[(a \land b) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b)] \land c\} \lor \{\lnot[(a \land b) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b)] \land \lnot c\}
\\\equiv[(a=b)\land c]\lor[(a\ne b)\land \lnot c]
\\\equiv(a=b)=c$$